# Rails 3 using Phusion Passenger with apache doesn't work in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails3, Phusion passenger 3 and apache.
I have fairly simple app with one controller and one view to print hello world.
if remove this line from the vhost "RailsEnv development" i got http 500 error as follow
"500 Internal Server Error".
And if i put back the line "RailsEnv development" the app works fine.
Is there something about passenger that needs to be set for production to work?

I simply need to test whether my new passenger install will work in production mode.

Below are relevant configurations.
    [usertest@test-server web_app1]$ ruby -v
    ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606)

```
[usertest@test-server web_app1]$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

[usertest@test-server web_app1]$ cat /etc/apache/conf.d/passenger.conf 
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-   3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.18
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName siteexample.com 
 DocumentRoot  /var/www/mysites/apps/web_app1/public   
 RailsEnv development
<Directory /var/www/mysites/apps/web_app1/public>    
     AllowOverride all        
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews   
     Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Overall, config looks right.  Not taking anything for granted: please confirm the the space in `...gems/passenger-   3.0.18/ext...` is just a formatting error.  Also, please confirm that you have a properly configured file `apps/config/environment/production.rb`.  If all of this is right, please look in the 1) the rails log (which may or may not be the production.log, and 2) Apache log.

Comment: yeah look in production.log.  My guess is that your production database doesn't exist, or you can't contact it/write to it or the like.  The internal server error shows that you are in production mode (hide error messages from end user)  Dev mode would show the stack trace

Comment: @tharrison: That space is just when i pasted here. But, what do you mean by property configured /config/environment/production.rb. I have't touch file at all and not sure what should go in.

Comment: production log is saying: ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to deploy to a production server with Phusion Passenger you need to use the `RailsEnv production` directive as you have.

But you also need to ensure that the associated Rails environment is configured correctly.  These files are stored in `apps/config/environments/` and a new Rails project comes with 3: `development` (the default), `test`, and `production`.  You can add others, for example `staging` by adding files to this directory.

Each file has a number of settings that make sense for the environment.  In development, you want nice verbose logging, plain-text CSS and JS files, and errors to show up in the browser.  In production, you want everything to be as fast as possible: terse logging, compiled assets, user-friendly error pages.

In your case, the assets used by Rails (notably all of the CSS and JS files) have not yet been processed by the Rails "asset pipeline".  There's a rake task for precompiling assets (`rake assets:precompile`) which is what the default `production` environment expects.  The default development environment compiles CoffeeScript and SASS files to JS and CSS respectively on the fly, and does minimal processing otherwise.

So as part of deploying to production, you'll need to run this rake task any time you add or make a change to any assets.  Because this and numerous other similar details are required every time you deploy, there's a great gem called Capistrano, which most Rails apps use for deployment.  It's a whole other beast, to be sure, but as you get further along the process, you'll definitely want to consider it.  Even a minimally configured capistrano script would know to precompile assets and restart the server when it's done, etc.

Comment: tharrison: I appreciated your time and answer. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `RailsEnv production`

Restart Apache and then restart Passenger with `touch /var/www/mysistes/apps/web_app1/tmp/restart.txt`

Comment: I did restarted both apache and app multiple times. When  you say set "RailsEnv Production" you mean just commandline? I'm not having problems with the commandline but to run the app in passenger production mode. I have no problem when i set the following in vhost either "RailsEnv development" problem is when i change development to production in that statement.

Comment: Ah I read in your question you removed the RailsEnv development line. Have you tried switching that line to production?

Comment: I haven't. I read passenger is by default set to production and when i remove the development statement i can see logs in production.log which means its pointing to prod by default without that statement being there. Appreciated the help though

Comment: I just saw your last comment. Add `gem 'therubyracer'` to your Gemfile then run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`